# popup blocker detection in js for chrome(v95 and above)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, popup-blocker

```
    var newWin = window.open(url);             

    if(!newWin || newWin.closed || typeof newWin.closed=='undefined') 
    { 
        //POPUP BLOCKED
        alert('blocked');
    } else {
        alert('enabled');
    }
```

This code only works for first time when I newly loaded site in chrome. But once I allow popup and agin disabled it from chrome site setting still it opens window and gives alert as 'enabled'

Comment: Well that it reports "enabled", when the popup was actually able to open, should be natural. Are you talking about changing this setting without reloading the page afterwards here, or what exactly is the scenario?

Comment: When I changed site setting from allow to block and reload site, window should not open and it should gived alert 'blocked'

Comment: But obviously _that_ part is not working (so I'd call that a browser bug), but that doesn't mean that the alert you're getting is technically wrong.

Comment: can we read browsers setting from browser api like allowPopupsForUserEvents?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible.